# FreeBSD: /dev/dsp exists ("ls -al /dev/dsp"), but does not show in "ls -al /dev"

Tags: freebsd, devices

I'm using `FreeBSD-12.0-RELEASE-amd64`, when I list all the files in `/dev`, I don't see `/dev/dsp` (note there's no output after the first command), but when I list the file by explicitly specifying its name, it is found. Even more weird, when I then `ls -al /dev` again (and grep for `dsp`, like in the initial command), the `/dev/dsp` file disappears again, but now `/dev/dsp0.0` exists:

```
# ls -al /dev | grep dsp
# ls -al /dev/dsp
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel  0x56 May 24 07:46 /dev/dsp
# ls -al /dev | grep dsp
crw-rw-rw-   1 root  wheel     0x56 May 24 07:46 dsp0.0
```

The above has been done by running the ISO image in QEMU, but I was able to reproduce this on real hardware, too. Just boot with the default parameters, then select "Shell" in the menu that appears, then enter the commands from above:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -soundhw hda -cdrom FreeBSD-12.0-RELEASE-amd64-disc1.iso
```

And for the record:

```
# cat /dev/sndstat
Installed devices:
pcm0: <Generic (0x1af40022) (Analog)> (play/rec) default
No devices installed from userspace.
```

Listing `/dev` to me sounds like a good way to find out which devices / disks FreeBSD "sees", coming from a Linux background. There's probably some good reason (creating nodes on demand?) why it doesn't appear, but is there some other way to ask the system "what devices did you actually find and are available?" without having to "touch" the files for them to magically appear?

Comment: What is it that you're actually wanting to do? Get a list of the devices in general? Does `dmesg` give you any usable information? Does the `sysctl` utility help?

Comment: `/dev/` is not a normal directory any more. It's the mount point of the [`devfs(5)`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=devfs&apropos=0&sektion=5&manpath=FreeBSD+12.0-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html) file system.

Comment: I checked the `dmesg` output, I only found `pcm`-related messages. Didn't yet try `sysctl`. I read online that the sound device is `/dev/dsp`, and my initial hunch was "let's use ls to check if that file exists in `/dev`".

Comment: So the thing that I want to do is query `devfs` (or something) to see ALL devices that are installed/detected on my machine and that it would (dynamically / on-demand) create. Apparently devfs "changes" its content depending on which files I try to access, and being able to see what files could be there would help me in discovering which device nodes are available to me.

Comment: So presumably `/dev/dsp` is only created when you try to read it, right? Does it also create arbitrary names? I mean, does `ls /dev/jnkjasnd` work as well?

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work: `ls: /dev/jnkjasnd: No such file or directory`

Comment: `dmesg | grep pcm` to find sound devices. Status check `cat /dev/sndstat`. Test `cat file > /dev/dsp`. `/dev/dsp` created as needed. See [7.2.2. Testing Sound](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/sound-setup.html)

Comment: The point being that every such investigation starts with `dmesg` and not `ls /dev`. That is the usual pattern when working with FreeBSD.

Comment: Thanks @ClausAndersen, makes sense to start with `dmesg`, thanks also for the pointer to the "Testing Sound" section of the handbook. However, the "created as needed" part is what threw me off. I also checked the `devfs(5)` and `devfs(8)` man pages, but didn't find any reference to this on demand creation. So, is this "created as needed" documented somewhere?

Comment: It would be good if you could modify your question to be more precise.  Currently I don't know if you are asking about the behaviour of `/dev` on FreeBSD, or whether you are asking how to find your audio device.  If you want to know how to query the FreeBSD device tree, then this should be the question.

Comment: Yes - it is documented in the FILES section of [man pcm](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pcm&sektion) which lists the various /dev/dsp variants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all the comments. The main takeaways for me were:

1. Do not use `ls /dev` for checking which devices are on the system, but use `dmesg` instead (and in the particular case of sound cards, [7.2.2 Testing Sound](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/sound-setup.html) is really useful)
2. `devfs` has the ability to create device nodes on demand (when they are first accessed)

The mentioned [`sound(4)`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sound&sektion=4) manpage says:

> The above device nodes are only created on    demand through the dynamic `devfs(5)` clone handler.

The "clone handler" there is - as far as I understood it - [`dev_clone(9)`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=dev_clone&sektion=9&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2B10.0-RELEASE), and indeed [dsp.c](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/311df7ee73edd66e677e270e3c6c82e1879fdc61/sys/dev/sound/pcm/dsp.c) in the FreeBSD sources calls it in `dsp_sysinit()`, the code that creates the `/dev/dsp0.0` entry above:

```
        *dev = make_dev(&dsp_cdevsw, PCMMINOR(udcmask),
            UID_ROOT, GID_WHEEL, 0666, "%s%d%s%d",
            devname, unit, devsep, cunit);
```

While researching, I also stumbled upon [Rethinking /dev and devices in the UNIX kernel](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/publications/library/proceedings/bsdcon02/full_papers/kamp/kamp_html/index.html) by Poul-Henning Kamp in BSDCon 2002, which in "On-demand device creation" says:

> An interesting mixed use of this mechanism is with the sound device drivers. Modern sound devices have multiple channels, presumably to allow the user to listen to CNN, Napstered MP3 files and Quake sound effects at the same time. The only problem is that all applications attempt to open `/dev/dsp` since they have no concept of multiple sound devices. The sound device drivers use the cloning facility to direct `/dev/dsp` to the first available sound channel completely transparently to the process.
>
> There are very few drawbacks to this mechanism, the major one being that `ls /dev` now errs on the sparse side instead of the rich when used as a system device inventory, a practice which has always been of dubious precision at best.